# Basic Authentication to web service with C#

Tags: c#, web-services, basic-authentication, service-reference

I have a Web Service that require basic authentication. I test it with a small java program.

substantially:

```
...
String authorization = s + ':' + (s1 != null ? s1 : "");
authorization = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(authorization2.getBytes());
httpurlconnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authorization);
....
```

This works fine. But I have to deal this with a C# program. I add a "Service Reference" in my project by importing wsdl file.
After a lot of search, I think this would be the deal:

```
WSHttpBinding binding = new WSHttpBinding();
binding.Name = "pisconfigwebserviceSOAP";
EndpointAddress epAdd = new EndpointAddress(remoteAddress);
myWebserviceClient client = new myWebserviceClient(binding, epAdd);

ContractDescription cd = ContractDescription.GetContract(typeof(myWebservice), typeof(myWebserviceClient));
  client.Endpoint.Contract = cd;

// this part should add the Basic Authentication to the header. Or not?
using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel)) {
    var httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
    httpRequestProperty.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mUserName + ":" + mPassword)));
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, httpRequestProperty);

    int result = client.AddOrUpdate(obj);
}
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, try many many different things and I am sticking here.
I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this out for the last section of your code. When I test this, I can see the "Authorization" header is populated.

```
using (var scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{
    var hrmp = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
    hrmp.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mUserName + ":" + mPassword));

    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = hrmp;

    int result = client.AddOrUpdate(obj);
}
```